# Increasing CMS security by 404'ing everything that is not supposed to be visible

Tags: security, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I produced a simple .htaccess file which prevents users from loading url's that are inside the system core folder. However this is not fully working.

If I load `http://domain.com/systemfolder/`, I get `404 File not found`, so that's cool, but if I enter `http://domain.com/systemfolder` (note that the URL is without trailing `/`), mod_dir redirects if from `http://domain.com/systemfolder` to `http://domain.com/systemfolder/`. If I disable `mod_dir` for that particular directory, I get `401 Permission denied` instead of `404 File not found`, so the attacker is able to identify my system. How do I fix that?

Additional info: I'm using `mod_rewrite` for the 404'ing.

My current .htaccess (that is in all the system's folders that are in system root) looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c> 
    DirectorySlash Off 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L] 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c> 
    Order allow,deny Deny from all 
</IfModule>
```

---

You may ask yourself: WHY THE HELL IS HE DOING THAT???

The answer is simple: Basically any opensource CMS like Joomla!, WordPress or Drupal is vulnerable to attacks, because these are not 100 % bulletproof. Once a cracker finds a vulnerability, he basically tell thousands of crackers and they have opportunity to crack that system. The reason why these systems are not 100 % bulletproof is 10 % because human is only human and 90 % because there are thousands of people contributing to the system and not everyone produces secure code. This fact is compensated by fact that thousands of people can release the hotfix relatively quickly.

The cracker's first step is to identify such system. If he's capable of just punching in additional `wp-admin` in the url and it works, he basically identified WordPress site. Cracker's second step is to find the vulnerability. The third step is exploiting that vulnerability.

My approach there is to stop cracker at step number 1 so he's not able to identify the system. Of course there probably will be system's signature in the footer, but that requires human interaction. By masking every url and by key-based loading of web content (user will basically not be able to load any image or video if does not supply valid key in uri by loading the page that appends there one time keys at the end of the image url's). Administration will be on dedicated server, open only to certain IP's so yeah, I think it will be pretty secure.

Comment: Well, show the .htaccess file then? :)

Comment: Are you intending to develop a CMS because it'll be more secure than WP or Drupal? Because it won't. An open-source CMS has the benefit of hundreds of developers looking for security flaws, and you on your own are far more likely to have missed something. If you think you've found a flaw in an existing project, why not just patch it on your own system to fix the flaw, then if the patch works try to get it submitted.

Comment: @Nathan no, I think he wants to simply hide product-specific URLs from outside users, which is a wise additional security measure. (*Because*  if a cracker discovers an exploit in WP or Drupal, they have a wide variety of target choices). Still, without seeing the .htaccess file it is hard to tell what the problem is...

Comment: @NathanMacInnes Yeah, it's exactly what Pekka said.

Comment: The HTML markup of CMSs is very telling of what one you're running. Wordpress is a case in point, particularly once you start using plugins.

Comment: @Alex that can be controlled, though. (I agree however that you'll have to put some work in, e.g. to disguise the `/wp-content/themes` directory

Comment: or subscribe to release announcements and update your CMS regularly.